# Explanation for this error using cursor.execute in SQLite3 moduel

Tags: python-3.7

Any idea why this is failing? Just learning sqlite3 so I suspect I've made a simple mistake -- but I can't see it.

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE books(title text primary key, author text,read integer)')
```

I get:

> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute'

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem -- and as I expected, it was a stupid error.  I was missing () in my cursor creation statement a couple of lines earlier.  I don't understand how the stack trace would have led me to that conclusion (although I suspect it's obvious to someone with more Python experience then I have at the moment.)

Back to learning this very cool language...
charlie